# Disabling a div with jquery for time

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to put a timer on a div to be disabled for certain amount of time. for example 3 seconds here is the html code.

```
<div class="answ-container" align="center">
      <div class="c_answer" id="1316" name="1" data-rcat-no="1">
          <p>Strongly Disagree</p>
      </div>
      <div class="c_answer" id="1316" name="2" data-rcat-no="2">
          <p>Disagree</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

To disable all mouse click

```
var event = $(document).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});


// disable right click
    $(document).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    });
```

how can I enable it again after 3 seconds:

```
$(document).unbind('click');
$(document).unbind('contextmenu');
```

Comment: try using .on() and .off()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could clean this up a bit and use a css class to handle the click events:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.c_answer').on('click touchstart', function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('disabled').delay(3000).queue(function(){
       $(this).removeClass('disabled').dequeue();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.c_answer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.disabled {
  opacity: 0.4;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answ-container" align="center">
      <div class="c_answer" id="1316" name="1" data-rcat-no="1">
          <p>Strongly Disagree</p>
      </div>
      <div class="c_answer" id="1316" name="2" data-rcat-no="2">
          <p>Disagree</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `setTimeout` method. It takes two parameters. A callback function, in which you add your code you want to run. The second parameter is the time you want to run the code after in milliseconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(document).unbind('click');
    $(document).unbind('contextmenu');
}, 3000);
```

Find out more [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/).

Comment: How do they get re-bound?

Comment: You should edit your code so that it first disables, then call the timeout and reenable rather than disable.

Comment: The OP asking how to bind it again. but you are telling how to unbind

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` to delay logic execution for a set time.

Also, rather than binding/unbinding elements on the fly, which can get messy, use a flag to determine whether or not the click handler should be allowed. Try this:

```js
$('body').data('mouse-enabled', false);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('body').data('mouse-enabled', true);
  $('.state').text('Mouse events enabled!'); // only for display in this example
}, 3000);

$(document).on('click contextmenu', function(e) {
  if (!$('body').data('mouse-enabled'))
    return false;

  console.log('event caught!');
  return true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answ-container" align="center">
  <div class="c_answer" id="1316" name="1" data-rcat-no="1">
    <p>Strongly Disagree</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c_answer" id="1316" name="2" data-rcat-no="2">
    <p>Disagree</p>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="state">Mouse events disabled...</p>
```

Note that I simplified the logic by joining the event handlers together and removing the multiple `event` object calls as `return false;` does the same job.